# Docker and ASP.NET Core 2.1 preview 1

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have installed ASP.NET Core 2.1 preview 1 from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/02/27/announcing-net-core-2-1-preview-1/) and the latest preview of Visual Studio.

Then I follow the steps: File > New Project > ASP.NET Core Web Application > Choose `API`, check `Enable Docker Support (Os: Linux)` and `No Authentication`.

This nicely generates project template, as well as a Docker project with docker compose files. This builds fine, and pulls all the required images. However, when I try to run it with Docker, from within Visual Studio, it doesn't seem to work.

In the logs I see the following:

> Content root path: /app
>   Now listening on: http://[::]:80
>   ...
>   Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:32778/
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:32778/

Now, when I try to do a GET to http://localhost:32778/api/values (using Postman), no response is seen:

> Could not get any response
>   There was an error connecting to http://localhost:32778/api/values.

BUT! The Docker logs show that the request is being made:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:32778/api/values
>   [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>   Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:32778/api/values
>   [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>   Request finished in 14.4873ms 307
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 14.4873ms 307

What am I missing here? If I run the default project with IIS Express, everything works as expected.

EDIT: I've just tested this on ASP.NET Core 2.0, and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 8):

As @andrewbadera pointed out, the repositories changed:

#### SDK

Old : `microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0`

New: `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk`

#### ASP NET

Old : `microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0`

New: `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime`

I don't know why the template from visual studio is not using it already, but soon they probably will fix this.

Visual Studio template is generating:

SDK => `microsoft/aspnetcore:2.1`

ASP NET => `microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.1`

Answer (score 1):

I'm also struggling with netcoreapp2.1 on Docker. Are you sure that docker images are pulled down successfully? Because when I'm creating a new project, the created Dockerfile has:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.1 AS base
//...
//...
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.1 AS build
```

and from what I can see in the [microsoft docker repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/tags/), those images simply **do not exist** (!).

The output in VS shows:

```
========== Pulling Images ==========
Pulling missing Docker images. To cancel this download, close the command prompt window. To disable image auto-pull, see Tools > Options > Container Tools.
docker pull microsoft/aspnetcore:2.1
docker pull failed
```

The closest images I found are:

```
microsoft/aspnetcore:2.1.0-preview1
microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.1.300-preview1
```

and the app works, BUT there is another problem: while debugging in VS, the **debugger doesn't hit any breakpoints** (because PDB symbols are not loaded, I don't know why that happens).

Everything I just described, works when creating a new ASP.NET Core **2.0** project.

Comment: Same boat here.